# OSError: exception: access violation in iewin.IEHtmlWindow

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I was converting an application of mine from py2 to py3. The process includes migrating from wxPython Classic to Phoenix.

It is a GUI application that uses the wxPython [`IEHtmlWindow` class](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.iewin.IEHtmlWindow.html).

When I execute the application I get this error:

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFF903EED60
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wx\lib\activex.py", line 154, in MSWTranslateMessage
    res = self.ipao.TranslateAccelerator(msg)
```

Each movement of the mouse inside the HTML window, produces this error.

Trying to debug the problem, I copied the TestPanel code of the [ActiveX_IEHtmlWindow.py](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/ActiveX_IEHtmlWindow.py) example in the Phoenix demo package into a python module named `html.py` (and renamed the `TestPanel` panel as `HtmlWin`). Then, I instantiated the demo IEHtml window with a minimal Frame:

```
import wx
from html import HtmlWin

class HtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title=title)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.html = HtmlWin(self, None)
        sizer.Add(self.html, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND )
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.SetSize((768,550))
        self.html.ie.AddEventSink(self)

class MyFrame(HtmlFrame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        HtmlFrame.__init__(self, title=title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame(title='test').Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I got the Phoenix demo IEHtml window as expected, but it also was producing the same OSError.

I was not having this error running wxPython classic (vs 2.8) on Python 2.7.
This is windows 10, 64bits and the more recent phoenix release (b2)

**UPDATE**

As the Exception messsage says, the exception occurs on the `MSWTranslateMessage` function of class `ActiveXctrl` in module **activex.py**.

```
def MSWTranslateMessage(self, msg):
    # Pass native messages to the IOleInPlaceActiveObject
    # interface before wx processes them, so navigation keys and
    # accelerators can be dealt with the way that the AXControl
    # wants them to be done. MSWTranslateMessage is called before
    # wxWidgets handles and eats the navigation keys itself.

    res = self.ipao.TranslateAccelerator(msg)

    if res == hr.S_OK:
        return True
    else:
        return super(ActiveXCtrl, self).MSWTranslateMessage(msg)
```

As a last resort solution, I catched the Exception on a `try/except` around the `res = self.ipao.TranslateAccelerator(msg)` line. After this change, it seems functionality of the IEHtmlWindow has not been affected.

Trying to get some clue on the problem, I captured the value of `msg` producing the exception:

```
<sip.voidptr object at 0x000002C1FD6AD5A8>
```

No idea what this means. Maybe someone can give me some hint from here to solve the problem in a clean way (without modifying the lib with the try/except)

**UPDATE 2  (2019)**

No solution yet. However someone had the same problem, [reported in github](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1290), and the report was read by wxpython people. Comments in the github report point to this same SO question.

Comment: I would suggest you open a issue with them on their git repo too

Comment: @TarunLalwani There is already a question on the google group for wxpython-users pointing to stack overflow. Robin Dunn and main programmers of wxPython use to be around. Just waiting for an answer here or there, before open an issue